# each not working on navigation links

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hi Friends I am working on a single page website . I want when user scroll and any section of text reaches top 0 the the appropriate link will turn red

You can check **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s89Lzuzz/)**  or checl my code below

**SCRIPT**

```
$( 'html, body' ).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll) {

                $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav li:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('active');
            }else {


        $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
    }
        });


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Jquery plugin to highlight header on scrolling page content. 
You can find more similar plugins like this as well

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Navigation-Menu-Highlighting-Plugin-visualNav.html

If you want to handle highlight on your own then use Jquery waypoint plugin

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Use $(window).scroll(function() { }) , JS fiddle Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/mcdmys3z/1/  . You may need to correct your logic as right now with your code last tab is not highlighting on scrolling to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution : See the working  demo  http://jsfiddle.net/mcdmys3z/1/**

You were doing few things wrong, below is the explanation of logic:

1) You were attaching scroll event on html/body but it does not work on them, scroll event gets fired on DOM objects like document/window/element etc. ,also note that while attaching events to DOM objects like document/window don't  wrap them in a string like $('window') as it will not work, correct way will be $(window).

2) Your logic to highlight link was not correct

(i) When user scrolls you have to check if (sectionTop >= scrollTop) i.e when user scrolls to top of a section then highlight its link. At this point the heading of section is touching top header bottom.

(ii)Also you have to consider section content height, when user scrolls down to section content i have to check if (sectionTop + sectionHeight)>=scrollTop then keep highlighting its link. This means scroll has not yet passed/moved to top of next section heading and still the current section content is visible.

(iii)Now when scroll passes to next section heading top i.e next section heading top is touching top header bottom then previous section highlight condition becomes false and now next section header link gets highlighted

3)You have to also consider top header height, subtract header height from $(this).position().top as your content hides behind sticky header. So the logical top in your case is top header bottom and not page top.

Some of your content is outside section Portfolio, is that intentional?

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('.section').each(function (i) {
            if (($(this).position().top - 92) >= windscroll || ($(this).position().top - 92 + $(this).height()) >= windscroll) {
                $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav li:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').addClass('active');
                return false; // To break Jquery each loop
            } else { // I don't think this is needed
                //$('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                // $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    })
```